# Increase access token time period in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating access token using this:

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize? client_id=127605460617602& scope=read_stream,user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream& redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/

then, It is giving me an access token which is valid for a limited time period.

after that i was using **offline_access** prms like this:

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
>   client_id=127605460617602&
>   scope=offline_access,read_stream,user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream&
>   redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/

then, It is giving me permanent access token.

Is there any way to create a access token according to my expiration time.

can any one help me.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid this is not possible. **BUT** you may use the following to "*expire*" the session (using [PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)):

```
$facebook->setSession(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, you can either have the facebook-defined expiry or the never-expires offline access token.