# Log out of Facebook Connect, but not Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I'm using Facebook PHP SDK to implement authorization through Facebook Connect on my website. It works fine, however, when a user logs out, he or she logs out of Facebook as well. I understand this is normal behaviour for clicking on a link which was generated using getLogoutUrl() method.

Is it possible for a user to log out of Facebook Connect, but not Facebook as well? If so, how can this be achieved?

Thank you in advance.

**UPD, sort of an answer:** For me, what it basically boiled down for was using Facebook Connect this way: user clicks the 'Facebook Connect' button; if they are logged in to Facebook and authorize the app (app is required for using Facebook Connect), we get their ID and set a cookie that he's logged in. This cookie has no relation to Facebook, it's created by my script. When the user wants to log out, we simply delete this cookie.

So, login and logout logic are based entirely in my script. FB Connect only aids the process by removing the need to get a password and a login for a user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increase access token time period in facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339013/increase-access-token-time-period-in-facebook)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply clear the facebook-connect-related cookies manually.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know exactly how to do that. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I'm also very interested in the solution

Comment: Use getSignedRequestCookieName() on the facebook SDK class and then get rid of them with setcookie($name, NULL, -1);

Comment: I had this problem. For some reason `setcookie($facebook->getSignedRequestCookieName(), '', time() - 3600);` did not work, and `setcookie($facebook->getSignedRequestCookieName(), '', time() - 3600, '/');` did work.

Comment: It could possibly be the params I'm passing to FB.init, but facebook automatically re-creates the cookie if you're logged into FB and have already connected with the app.  That's why this method hasn't worked in my experience.